# How to pause Jquery div slider on mouseover and restart it on mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, slideshow

Good evening,
I have prepared jsfiddle Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/Z6Y95/1/

this is the html:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="stop" id="dev" >a1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="stop" id="facebook" > a2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="stop" id="seo">a3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="stop" id="support">a4</a></li></ul>
<div id="serviceimg" class="serviceimg">
<div class="hide" name="dev" style="background:red;color:#fff;">a1</div>
<div class="hide" name="facebook" style="background:red;color:#fff;">a2</div>
<div class="hide" name="seo" style="background:red;color:#fff;">a3</div>
<div class="hide" name="support" style="background:red;color:#fff;">a4</div>
</div>
```

This is a working jquery div slider, but I need to pause it on a href mouse over and show specific div associated with this a. 
On mouse out it has to continue div sliding but in my case on mouse out I am getting a few seconds pause without and div shown. 
How to start div sliding on mouse out?

Thank you in avance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the updated JS code:

```
$('.serviceimg div').hide(); // hide all slides
    $('.serviceimg div:first-child').show(); // show first slide

    var prop;



    prop = setInterval(function () {
        $('.serviceimg div:first-child').hide()
            .next('div').show()
            .end().appendTo('.serviceimg');
    }, 3000);

    $('div').hover(function () {

        clearInterval(prop);

    }, function () {
        console.log('out');
        prop = setInterval(function () {
            $('.serviceimg div:first-child').hide()
                .next('div').show()
                .end().appendTo('.serviceimg');
        }, 3000);
        return false;
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6Y95/4/)**

SetInterval can be very "dangerous" because it can stack when you hover. I used `return false` to prevent that.

The `.hover` function turned out to be the most suitable for your case. You can read more about it **[here](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)** .

Comment: thanks for helping me. Your fiddle doesn't work diffrent way than mine. Still I can see 1-2 seconds delay after mouse out trigger.. which shoudn't be.. Somewhere I read that jquery setinterval() must be paused, but didn;t understand how.. and dont see solution for this in your fiddle - correct?

Comment: Oooh I understand now: 

 Do you want something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/Z6Y95/3/

Comment: No man, this is not issue that can be solved via css. I don't see difference between your both jsfiddles.. I mean you did not add any js script, correct? Still I can see the delay I ment at the begining..

Comment: GIve me a few seonds, I will see what I can do

Comment: Ok, I updated my solution. Sorry for misunderstanding you!

 Now every time you hover over the div, it freezes. When you hover out, it continues. I hope this will work for you!

Comment: Hristo, where is the updated solution? jsfiddle.net/Z6Y95/4 doesn't work on mouseover.. On mouse over it doesnt show the specific div.. At least on IE.. Yesterday I went to bed :)

Comment: Hristo, jsfiddle.net/Z6Y95/4 doesn't work on a class="stop" mouseover.. The idea was on class="stop" hover to hide all divs exept the div with attr name equal to a triger ID. this fiddle works different way mate :)

Comment: Sorry for not being able to help you completely! Molya :D

Comment: Your code was good base for me and after I change it it works and I accept your answer Hristo. Mersi ! :) here is working http://jsfiddle.net/Z6Y95/6/